# Facebook website app that doesn't use Facebook Login for multiple websites

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am currently testing the Instagram Graph API for the purposes of obtaining, with the website owner's permission, his recent Instagram posts to fill an image slider or gallery with the image/thumbnail, like and comment count and a redirect to the post's permalink on click.

The plan is for this to be used like a widget that can be added to client websites, changing the Instagram Business Username used to obtain the website owner's Instagram feed via the Business Discovery API.

**This app does not make use of Facebook Login**, all it does is fetch X number of Instagram posts and show them in the client's website.

**Can I use a single app for all the websites or is it necessary to create a new app for each website**? Hopefully the former, because the latter would quickly become cumbersome as we have many websites interested in such a feature.

---

Question Details

- **Does not use Facebook Login**
- Permissions used: instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights
- Uses our Instagram Business Account ID and the client's Business Username in conjunction with the Business Discovery API to retrieve posts
- Shows posts in an image slider or gallery, redirects to post permalink on click

Comment: If there is no login, then whose access token are you going to use? Yours? Then the whole part of requesting data from the API should only happen on your own server to begin with, your own access token is something you should never expose to third parties.

Comment: @misorude The websites are hosted on our servers, so the access token is never visible to others.

Comment: Then this should work perfectly fine. Login functionality and embedding the JavaScript SDK are affected by domain restrictions - but server-side API calls are not limited by that. (Those are usually not made “from” a specific domain to begin with, the API only sees the server IP address.)

Comment: @misorude That is good to know, but it doesn't answer the question, which is whether or not we have to create an app for each website we implemented the widget on. Facebook's documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about it.

Comment: Not for the server-side API calls, no. (If you wanted to embed the JS SDK to use the social plugins Facebook provides to _display_ those posts, it might.)